# CoreData saves data twice when calling saveContext()

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am currently building a story feature in my iOS app. Like on Instagram and Snapchat. The story also has a circle around the image. It changes the color if the story has been seen.

At the start of the App, I save some values in CoreData to identify every story.

```
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
        var storys = [Story]()
        
        
        private init() {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            fetchStoryItems()
        }
    
        func addStorys(with shoeID: String, raffles: String, seenStory: Bool) {
            let storyItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Story", into: context) as! Story
            
            storyItem.shoeID = shoeID
            storyItem.newRaffles = raffles
            storyItem.seen = seenStory
            
            if !storys.contains(where: {$0.shoeID == shoeID}) {
                
                    storys.append(storyItem)
                    saveContext()
               
            }
            
            
        }

   func fetchStoryItems() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Story> = NSFetchRequest<Story>(entityName: "Story")

        do {

            let storyItemsArray = try context.fetch(request)

            storys = storyItemsArray

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    
    func saveContext() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

This works fine and every value is stored once in CoreData. So that the circle is displayed in the correct color, I change the value if the story has been seen. If the user taps von a story the following methods are executed.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        CoreDataStoryCheck.sharedInstance.storyTapped(with: Array(storyShoeModel.values)[indexPath.row].ID!, seenStory: true)
        collectionViewOrTableView = 1
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: indexPath.row)
    }
    
        func storyTapped(with shoeID: String, seenStory: Bool) {
            
            if let story = storys.first(where: {$0.shoeID == shoeID && $0.seen == false}) {
                story.setValue(true, forKey: "seen")
                saveContext()
            }
    
        }
```

Now here comes my issue: Every time I am calling this method my data duplicates in CoreData. I have found that this happens every time when I call ***saveContext()***. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Set breakpoint and look in callstack, who is calling `saveContext`

Comment: I already did this and saveContext is only called on these two methods above.

Comment: From where do you call addStorys? You have a logical error in addStorys, first you create an object and _then_ you check if it already exists but since you have created the object it will remain in the managed object context so whenever you next save the context this object will be saved. So change the logic to first check if the object (shoeID) exists before creating it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you are absolutely right. Now I creating the object inside the if statement. Thank you!